# Conventions for ES6 iterables?

Tags: javascript, conventions, ecmascript-6, iterable

I'm the author of a [graph datastructure library](https://github.com/mhelvens/js-graph) for JavaScript. I'm currently [ES6-ifying](https://github.com/mhelvens/js-graph/tree/es6ify) the library.

I also want to make it more usable for ES6 programmers, which means implementing the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_.22iterable.22_protocol). But a graph has multiple things to iterate over, and multiple ways to iterate over them (vertices, edges, successors, predecessors, vertices in topological order, etc.)

I have an idea of how to design this interface, but I'd like to follow existing conventions if they exist. Here's an example of how I might do the 'vertices' part:

```
class JsGraph {
    // ...
    get vertices() {
        return {
            _graph: this,
            get length() { return this._graph._vertexCount },
            *[Symbol.iterator]() {
                var keys = Object.keys(this._graph._vertices);
                for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
                    yield [keys[i], this._graph._vertices[keys[i]]];
                }
            }
        };
    }
    // ...
}
```

If there are any existng convention I should probably be following (or any problems with this code), your feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some inspiration from the `Map` and `Set` ES6 data structures. They do provide multiple methods to get different iterators: `.values()`, `.keys()`, and `.entries()`. Their `@@iterator` method defaults to `entries` or `values` respectively.

I don't know of any other existing conventions, I guess these will have to form yet.

> any problems with this code

First, I'm not sure whether the getter `vertices` that returns such an object is a good idea. I'd rather do

```
get vertexCount() { … }
vertices*() { … }
```

but that'll basically come down to preference. Your current code is not as efficient because it creates two functions at every `.vertices` access, you could improve that using prototypes if you see the need (`class VertexIterator {…}`?).

Second, iterators on mutable data are a hazzle to implement, as it may change while being looped over. You should be aware of that and choose a strategy (making your structures immutable is probably out of question). For example, the MapIterator's `next` method is specified to "*redetermine the number of elements each time it is evaluated.*". Similarly, for object enumerations (`for in`) there is the rule that deleted properties must never appear (if not already enumerated before they were deleted), and of course no property may be enumerated twice. However, they explicitly are allowed to be inconsistent about keys that are added during the execution, no guarantees are given on whether those appear in the enumeration or not.

Comment: Thanks! Quite useful all around. **[1]** If `Map` and `Set` use function-call notation to get specific iterators, I'll do the same. **[2]** In that case, having a `.length` property right there (to make it feel like an array) somewhat loses its appeal, so I'll take your advice on that too. **[3]** A very good point. I'll probably be conservative in my specifications to start with. The guarantees made by object enumerations seem attainable.

Comment: "Second, iterators on mutable data are a hazzle to implement", copy-on-write data structures and/or snapshotting may be of use in some cases, similar to non-live DOM NodeLists.